# Time duration always 00:00:00 for Qt label

Tags: c++, qt, media-player, qtmultimedia, qmediaplayer

I've been trying to get the duration of a video file that's opened but whenever I open the file the duration always comes out to 00:00:00. I believe the logic and math are correct but that I am possibly missing a connection.

[GitHub](https://github.com/AdamElt/AtomMediaPlayer)

```
void MainWindow::updateDurationInfo(qint64 duration) {
 int seconds = (duration/1000) % 60;
 int minutes = (duration/60000) % 60;
 int hours = (duration/3600000) % 24;

QTime time(hours, minutes,seconds);

ui->label->setText(time.toString()); }

updateDurationInfo(player->duration());
```

Comment: `QTime time = QTime::fromMSecsSinceStartOfDay(duration);` would be simpler. Please show a [mre] in the question without relying on external links

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You set current position only in construction of window, but doesn't change it.
Try to connect signal that emit when player position changed to updateDurationInfo